Distinguish between two keyboards by USB identifier, to map one key differently on each?
Ubuntu Version: Currently using Ubuntu 20.04 underneath Mint Linux 20.3 then moving to Ubuntu 24.04 in near-term, underneath Mint Linux 22 next. Waiting for new machine to arrive.

Is it possible to distinguish different USB devices that are otherwise identical with xbindkeys?
I have two identical keyboards on the same machine, and would like the same key to behave differently, depending on which keyboard... presumably by USB identifier in some way, but xev does not seem to show that information.

This question is distilled down from a longer post here, with detailed walkthrough of the use case:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2551460#p2551460

Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

@user68186 currently 20.04 underneath Mint Linux 20.3 then moving to 24.04 in a little while, underneath Mint Linux 22 ( and updated question )

Also added tags, as well as versions in question.

See What topics can I ask about here? in this site's help. "Questions regarding Linux distributions which are not covered above, even if they are "based on" Ubuntu or Debian. This includes, but is not limited to: Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Kali Linux, and Pop!_OS. For questions regarding non-Canonical, non-Ubuntu distributions, try our friends at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange."
